# How do I make modules run sequentially?

Tags: verilog

In the top module of my design I call two other modules, but they run in parallel. I'd like to make then run one after another, so as soon as one finishes, the other one starts.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share some sample code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You do not call modules you instantiate them. You are describing two blocks of hardware which are in parallel. If you need a sequence then you need to create a state machine to control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first module output a DONE signal which it keeps low while busy and drives 1 when it's finished. The second module should wait till DONE goes 1 before it does anything. For e.g.

```
module A (
    output reg done
);
    initial begin
        done = 0;

        // Do all procesing

        done = 1;
    end
endmodule

module B (
    input done
);
    initial begin
        @(done == 1);  // Wait till done goes high

        // Start processing
    end
endmodule
```

BTW, this simple example assumes all the code in the modules are inside the initial blocks. If there are multiple always/initial blocks or combinational logic, figuring out when to drive DONE high can get trickier

Answer (score 0):

Use a push signal to run in the first instantiation  and wait for the push signal to go high  to signal the start of second instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use enable signal to control your  module.

For example, if module B needs to be  activated after module A is finished,

you can make module A to output a signal as the enable signal of module B after

module A is finished.The output signal of A can be initialized by reset signal.